# How to set credentials in private pod in pipeline azure devops iOS project

Tags: ios, azure, azure-devops, cocoapods, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to make a pipeline from an iOS Project in Azure DevOps, but when I tried to install the Cocoapods, the pipeline failed because one of the pods needs credentials 'cause is a private repository. The question is:

"How can I add the credentials in pipeline agent to authenticate the private pod repository?"

I attach the screen shot from my error. [screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWBHX.png)

Answer (score 4):

As workaround , you can use a script with Pre-Job as follows:

```
git config --global url."https://$(GitHub.Token)@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

And then a Post-Job script which should always run as follows:

```
git config --global --remove-section url."https://$(GitHub.Token)@github.com/"
```

You can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/363163/sharing-git-https-credentials.html) with similar issue .

Comment: thank you !!! really helped, also works for bamboo was searching for solution a months...

Answer (score 0):

You can add external credentials by ading a service connection.

To add a service connection you have to go to Settings => Service Connection => New service connection:

[image]

Then follow the steps to connect the service and then in your yml file you can define "externalFeedCredentials" with the name of your service this is an example for a private nuget server:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(MyPathVariable)'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '.nuget/NuGet.config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'NAME OF YOUR SERVICE'
```

I think you should be able to something like this for the pod repository.